# error in displaying data filed value as a tooltip in folium map

Tags: python, geojson, folium

I am trying to display data filedvalue as a tooltip in folium map
but I get this error
code:

```
index = 'hdi'
df = pd.DataFrame( [['United States of America',98],["Norway",99]], columns =['Country', index])
print (df)

url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/python-visualization/folium/master/examples/data'
country_shapes = f'{url}/world-countries.json'

m = folium.Map(tiles = 'Stamen Terrain',min_zoom = 1.5)


choropleth = folium.Choropleth(
    geo_data=country_shapes,
    name='choropleth COVID-19',
    data=df,
    columns=['Country', index],
    key_on='feature.properties.name',
    fill_color='YlGnBu',
    nan_fill_color='white'
).add_to(m)

choropleth.geojson.add_child(folium.features.GeoJsonTooltip(
        fields=['name',index],
        aliases=['Country', index],
        style=('background-color: grey; color: white;'),
        localize=True
        )
)
m.save('file_name')
```

I get this error
AssertionError: The field hdi is not available in the data. Choose from: ('name',).

Answer (score 1):

A little bit late. But for anyone needs a solution:

```
choropleth.geojson.add_child(folium.features.GeoJsonTooltip(
        fields=['name','index'],
        aliases=['Country:', 'Index:'],
        style=('background-color: grey; color: white;'),
        localize=True
        )
)
```

would do the work.